# Dynamic Dropdown in html form which changes the datalist on choosing a value from previous input

Tags: javascript, php, html

I wanted a dropdown that would change its options according to the value selected within an initial dropdown.
Here is an example : http://www.game-debate.com/can-I-run/
And here is the code when i click on 3rd gen all the processors from 3rd gen should be in the next data list.

```
<form>              
    <table border="1">
        <tr>
            <td>Processor</td>
            <td><input list="browsers" name="browser">
                  <datalist id="browsers">
                    <option value="Core2Duo">
                    <option value="i3">
                    <option value="i5">
                    <option value="i7">
                    <option value="Xeon">
                  </datalist>
            </td>
            <td><input list="progen" name="progen">
                  <datalist id="progen">
                    <option value="1st Gen">
                    <option value="2nd Gen">
                    <option value="3rd Gen">
                    <option value="4th Gen">
                  </datalist>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Ram</td>
            <td><input type="text"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Motherboard</td>
            <td><input type="text"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Ram</td>
            <td><input type="text"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Harddrive</td>
            <td><input type="text"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>SSD</td>
            <td><input type="text"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Graphics card</td>
            <td><input type="text"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Optical drive</td>
            <td><input type="text"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Power supply</td>
            <td><input type="text"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Cabinet</td>
            <td><input type="text"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Monitor</td>
            <td><input type="text"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Keyboard</td>
            <td><input type="text"></td>
        </tr>       
        <tr>
            <td>Mouse</td>
            <td><input type="text"></td>
        </tr>
</form>
</table>
```

Comment: So, build it! ;-) Now, what's the question?

Comment: i tried but not able to !

Comment: *"i tried but not able to !"* - I don't see any code in your question to support that.

Comment: i have just made a data list and have no idea what to use i know basics of php & javascript. am not able to add it to my post.

Comment: Ignore those who post arrogant comments - they are not nice people. Maybe upload your code to some external resource and provide a link if you can't post it here. It would be nice to see what you've done so far rather than asking for a ready made solution. Good luck

Comment: @MarinaDunst.Yeah its just above I was able to post since i have no idea about what am suppose to use for making it dynamic i dint follow up using php or javascript ,i googled but wasnt able to find out i dont need the ready made code i need to know how it works so I can make my own, and thanks a lot.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The way I would do it is by getting the index or value of the selected item and then use it to change other datalists.

For example this is how to obtain the value.

```
 document.getElementById("progen").selectedIndex;
    alert(document.getElementsByTagName("option")[x].value);
```

Try playing with [this example from w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_option_value.asp)

And [this example](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_select_selectedindex.asp)

Let me know if its not clear, I will try to help you.